# How to create an if statement in Xamarin forms for performing a certain action when the user has successful shared

Tags: c#, if-statement, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a click event in my Xamarin form Page that when a user clicks on the share button to share a string of text "Check out this amazing app! Download it now". Am using Xamarin essentials API. Bellow is the code:-

```
private async void ShareApp_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Specify the text you want to share
        string shareText = "Check out this amazing app! Download it now.";

        // Share the app using Xamarin.Essentials Share API
        var result = Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
        {
            Text = shareText,
            Title = "Share the App"
        });


        referralCount++;

        // Update the label text to display the current referral count
        referralCountLabel.Text = $"Referral Count: {referralCount}";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions related to sharing
        await DisplayAlert("Error", $"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}", "OK");
    }
}
```

I want the line

`referralCount++;`

to be executed only if the user has clicked on any share options and successful share the string.

I am new to programming I have tried searching online in different sources also tried chatGPT but couldn't find the answer

Comment: You don't get a callback even natively if the user has done this, its impossible to do, unless of course you create your own share UI and set it up somehow to do it

Comment: Oky how can I do it  @FreakyAli ?

Comment: I am not 100% certain if this will work but you need to create your Share UI and then find the correct URL for each app you want to support, otherwise, this is not doable

Comment: You can refer to the official doc: [Xamarin.Essentials: Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android).